# IntelliJ Idea - How to specify options while generating domain objects from DB tables

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, ide, intellij-idea, code-generation

I want to learn how can I specify some settings like **collection type**, **default fetch type**, **id generation strategy**, etc. using **IntelliJ Idea 11** while generating domain objects from database tables as we can do at NetBeans or Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

IDEA has no this feature, you are welcome to [submit a request to the issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).